# regex to modificate domino http log to common format for Piwik import

Tags: regex, bash, lotus-domino, matomo

I need to import old http log files from my Domino webserver into my piwik tracking. 
the problem is the format of the log if an user is logged in. 
Normal/good format example:

```
123.123.123 www.example.com - [17/Mar/2013:00:00:39 +0100] "GET /example.org HTTP/1.1" 200 3810 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" 234 "" "example"
```

Bad format example - produced if user is logged in

```
123.123.123 www.example.com  "CN=SomeUser/OU=SomeOU/O=SomeO" - [17/Mar/2013:00:00:39 +0100] "GET /example.org HTTP/1.1" 200 3810 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" 234 "" "example
```

i am looking for a one-liner bash to remove those CN information if it is included.

**UPDATE:**
this is my solution to get a one liner to import an domino log file into piwik. maybe someday someone finds this thing and needn't flip his table

```
for i in `ls -v *.log`; do date && echo " bearbeite" $i && echo " "  && awk '{sub(/ +"CN=[^"]+" +/," - ")}1' $i  grep -v http.monitor | grep -v nagios  > $i.cleanTmp && python /var/www/piwik/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py --url=http://127.0.0.1/piwik --idsite=8 $i.cleanTmp --dry-run && rm $i.cleanTmp; done;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You need a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution You can do something like this:

Example file

```
cat >infile <<XXX
123.123.123 www.example.com  "CN=SomeUser/OU=SomeOU/O=SomeO" - [17/Mar/2013:00:00:39 +0100] "GET /example.org HTTP/1.1" 200 3810 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" 234 "" "example"
XXX

while read x; do
    [[ $x =~ \ +\"CN=[^\"]+\"\ + ]] && x=${x/$BASH_REMATCH/ }
    echo $x
done <infile
```

Output:

```
123.123.123 www.example.com - [17/Mar/2013:00:00:39 +0100] "GET /example.org HTTP/1.1" 200 3810 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" 234 "" "example"
```

It parses for a string starting with spaces then `"CN=` and then any non `"` characters, then a `"` then some spaces. If this patten found, it replaces with a space.

If the log files are big ones (>1MB) and this should be done periodically, then use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) instead of the pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution.

```
awk '{sub(/ +"CN=[^"]+" +/," ")}1' infile
```

Comment: *works!* i made a small mistake, the minus must be there instead of the CN... i added it between the last double qouotes. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to remove the `"CN=SomeUser/OU=SomeOU/O=SomeO"` part?

The regex to match that looks like this:

```
"CN=\w+\/OU=\w+\/O=\w+"
```

Comment: thanks for that, but _Distinguished Names_ can contain multiple CN OU U.